# Protect Identity with VPN using Cloud Services - Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, Dropbox, etc

Tags: vpn

If you are using onedrive or any other cloud storage system is your identity safe when you connect and want to browse using a VPN or should you shut down all USERNAME / PASSWORD required services before using a VPN connection in order to remain anonymous?

Comment: Since you have to authenticate to these services to use then, I'd say you can't be anonymous.

Comment: I will be shutting down the services in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a good question, especially considering that your browser's sessions are primarily saved as cookies and so the ip address you're coming from - vpn or not - doesn't really matter.  As a particularly egregious example, take facebook links on sites.  Those are loaded from facebook, which means you send them your cookie to then request them.  So if you're logged into facebook, facebook knows every site you visit and yes, your Ip too.

So the answer is yes.  To remain more anonymous on your VPN, you should only use incognito or private mode browser and never log into any identifying site that you also use without the vpn.

Comment: I do use a private firefox session, but my question is are my other services detectable?  I am going to check out with Wireshark.

Comment: There are many services on a computer that “phone home “ checking for updates, licensing, etc. Any one of them could give away your identity — not just ones that have a username/password.

Comment: Fyi my shortcut for Firefox is the following - "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -private  --- Very effective and the only browser I use will using VPN. I will be shutting down services before had.  Need to code a Powershell script to enable and disable.